# How to achieve animated circular background button pressed effect in UIButton?

Tags: android, ios, swift

### Animation

[image]

### Circular background pressed effect

[image]

In Android, I can achieve the above effect in pretty straightforward way, by using a system selector.

```
<Button
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:minHeight="56dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/actionBarItemBackground"
    android:text="1" />
```

---

However, currently, I try to implement such in iOS. I am using `UIButton`

[image]

Default `UIButton`'s press behaviour doesn't perform any fancy animation and end effect. It merely change the color of the button text.

I was wondering, in iOS, how can I achieve the same animation and end effect, as my Android's?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
class CustomBu:UIButton {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.height / 2
    }
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "backgroundColor")
        animation.duration = 0.2
        animation.repeatCount = 2
        animation.autoreverses = true
        animation.fromValue = UIColor.lightGray
        animation.toValue = UIColor.white
        self.layer.add(animation, forKey: "position")
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
            self.backgroundColor = .white
        }
    }
}
```